# ROIListener usage

Tags: java, imagej

I'm currently trying to make an ImageJ plugin that will make certain calculations based on two ROIs the user creates.

Currently, I'm just trying to get `ROIListener` to work correctly. The roiModified() function is never called. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The plugin loads and compiles fine.

```
public class Event_Listener implements PlugIn, RoiListener {

public void run(String arg) {
    if (IJ.versionLessThan("1.43o")) return;
    Roi.addRoiListener(this);
    IJ.log("Event_Listener started");
}

@Override
public void roiModified(ImagePlus imp, int id) {
    System.out.println(id);
    switch(id) {
    case RoiListener.CREATED:
        imp.getRoi().setFillColor(Color.black);
        System.out.println("ROI Created");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems someone (possibly you) have created an [issue on github](https://github.com/imagej/imagej/issues/169) for this, and it has been solved now.

Note that questions related to ImageJ usage and development are best asked on the [**ImageJ forum**](http://forum.imagej.net/).